# Regex exercise - matching substring not followed by special char.

Tags: .net, regex

I'm struggling writing regex exp in dot net, which is supposed to capture all items in string that start with # char followed by [a-zA-Z0-9_]+. 
Problem is that I would like to avoid capture substrings that are followed by bracket "("
So from this example string "#REGNR() + #ORDER" I need to get following output in matches : "#ORDER"
I'm trying to achieve this with this regex:"(#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?!()))"
Problem is that I'm getting two matches :"#REGN" and "#ORDER", which s definetely not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much,

Peter

Comment: maybe `\b` will help you. so, it is the border of the world ;)
trying something like this: `#\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b(?!\(\))`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to find border of the word.

For this, just put `\b` <- border of the word, where you want.

In your exercise: `#\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b(?!\(\))`

It will match all you need (check here [regexs](http://rubular.com/))

Match whole word in `\b<WHOLE WORD>\b` not with special characters `()` at the end.

Comment: @PeterBoško no problem. FYI: it is important to SO be polite and if answer help you, you should (as a polite person) vote up answer and accept it with green stick below vote-arrows. best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
(#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))(?!\()
```

That way you're including the hash in your grouping. That will only match "#ORDER" in the following:

```
#REGNR() + #ORDER + #B() + BLAH
```